# Segfault on glBlendFunc

Tags: c++, opengl, segmentation-fault

I have the following code to begin a frame:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Without the last line, the program runs (but obviously does not blend), but with it it segfaults. GDB is not a lot of help, as it looks like the stack is corrupted, and after the segfault, running:

```
set $pc = *(void**)$rsp
set $rsp = $rsp+8
```

Points to the ending brace of the function as the last frame.

I have a small suspicion that this is a bug in the driver, but couldn't find a bug report on their tracker. The driver is flgrx-updates running on Ubuntu. GLXInfo gives:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon R9 200 Series
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.3.13399 Core Profile Context 15.201.1151
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.40
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
```

Comment: Did you look what `glGetError()` returns after calling `glEnable(GL_BLEND)`? Did you try other blending modes, e.g. `glBlendFunc(GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`?

Comment: Do you have last version of video driver?

Comment: @AntonMalyshev `glGetError()` returns `0` after the enable. Changing the blend mode still causes the crash

Comment: @Unick The latest version in the repository - I'm reluctant to update them manually. Using blending has worked for me before, so it's definitely my code or the driver reacting badly to something I've done *this time*

Comment: Try to restart machine :)

Comment: It's a long shot, but did you make sure that the GLX part matches the Xorg driver part (i.e. your libGL.so must match whatever the fglrx driver module for the X server is installed). Either way today there's little reason to use fglrx at all (most important one is, if you need OpenCL). AMDGPU/radeon have come a long way and in many applications have feature and performance parity.

Comment: @datenwolf what's the alternative to using fglrx? Should I switch to using AMD's official drivers?

Comment: @IsaacWoods: Mesa + AMDGPU/radeonhd, i.e. the open source drivers (that should have been installed by default by your Linux distribution installer). BTW: fglrx *are* the "official" AMD drivers; however AMD announced to phase out fglrx in the long run; and already the most recent versions of fglrx are using the AMDGPU kernel module. However even with that the GLX part and the X driver module must match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I still don't really know why this fixes it - but the seg fault was caused by me changing the order the object files were specified in the linking command. But specifying the object file that loads the function pointers to OpenGL **before** the file that uses those functions makes everything work nicely.

Comment: That actually sounds like you made some mistake with your GL loader. If you put the file before, it is not used when resolving the symbols of the following obj files. If you put a -lGL after that, you will directly link to the GL symbols, and not the loaders. So this sounds that this code is called before the loader is initialized, or the loader had some problems loading the pointers.

Comment: @derhass The loader is definitely initialising the function pointers (which are all valid, by the looks of it), is it possible smart linking is screwing the symbols up?